# What pixel values does the OpenCV's `imwrite` function write to a grayscale image?

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, colors

Im loading a grayscale image using:
`img_gray = cv.imread('gray_img.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`.
And writing it to a file using:
`cv.imwrite('test.png',img_gray)`.

Now my question is, how are the color channels stored in the resulting image file 'test.png'. Does the file posses a single color channel for each pixel or does it posses three color channels of equal intensities so that it appears grayscale?

I tried to read the image pixel values using an application called 'XNView' and it shows a pixel property called INDEX of singleton value that represents the intensity value of each pixel. But for a colored image it does not show the INDEX property, instead shows a property called RGB of three values Red, Green and Blue intensities. Does this mean OpenCV writes grayscale images with one pixel intensity values (the INDEX in XnView)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. A single channel.

Comment: Png allows single channel images. Other formats might not

Comment: JPEG does too. So does TIFF. Most formats allow single-channel images.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PNG ?